# Can you raise the variable of integration to a power like a second or third derivative?

Tags: calculus

I recently saw a poster claiming free WiFi if you could answer the integral. This is the integral: $$\int_{-2}^2{\left(x^3\cos\frac x 2+\frac 1 2\right)\sqrt{4-x^2dx}}$$the only problem is that the dx is under the square root. You could say this is a mistake and integrate and you would get $\pi$. But that answer is not satisfying. Is there any way in a loose sense you could say it is the $\frac 1 2$ integral? For example, I have seen the notation of a half derivative, $\frac {d^{1/2}f(x)} {dx^{1/2}}$ or a $3/2$ derivative, $\frac {d^{3/2}f(x)} {dx^{3/2}}$. I know it isn’t exactly standard, but as I don’t know if there is another way to deal with the $\sqrt {dx}$, can I call this the 1/2 integral? What would it look like to compute such an integral? Is there another better way to algebraically “get rid of” the square root around the dx?

Comment: You should probably start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: @RonKaminsky I just came back from reading that article and would like to know if the integral I posted is the same thing as $J^\frac 1 2$ on the integrand

Comment: $\sqrt{4-x^2dx}$ makes absolutely no sense. Are you sure it is not $\sqrt{(4-x^2)dx}$?

Comment: @user58697 it is in fact $\sqrt {4-x^2dx}$. Either way I don’t k ow how to deal with the $dx$ under the square root

Comment: @user58697 to be clear I’m pretty sure it is a typo and is supposed to be $\sqrt {4-x^2}dx$ because then the answer would be $\pi$ but my question is can the integral be answered with the $dx$ under the square root either through algebra or some kind of fractional calculus.

Comment: Pay attention to the root. I mean, $\sqrt{(4-x^2)}\sqrt{dx}$ _may_ make sense. $\sqrt {4-x^2dx}$ makes not.

Comment: @user58697 just to clarify, the poster has the integral the exact way I wrote it. I think it was a mistake and they meant $\sqrt {4-x^2}dx$. Although they probably messed up the poster, I would like to know if $\sqrt{4-x^2dx}$ is possible and what it may look like.

Comment: The form $4-x^2dx$ is ill-formed, no matter square root or not. Informally speaking, subtracting an infinitesimal from a constant is not defined.

Comment: @user58697 this is why I know the poster was a mistake but I want to know can it be done? Is there any way however informal to manipulate it and make it work?